# MySQL databases are gone when the docker container is shutdown

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-machine

I am new to docker world. I want to install some of the software packages into docker image. So I have taken Ubuntu:14.04 docker image and installed MySQL server there. Then did some works with it. Once I exit from docker image and commit it. But once I start docker container, databases which was created were gone. What would be the reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you start your mysql database with `docker run ...`, it creates each time a new and fresh container with it. You can find your old one in the list of containers with `docker ps -a` and you have to start your old container (`docker start <container>`) if you want the last state. Otherwise you have a fresh database derived from your image.