# IdentityServer4 key matarial configuration for Docker

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ssl-certificate, identityserver4, x509certificate2

I looked around [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) official GitHub for configuring signing credential (certificate) for production, but i can't find any example. Specific thing for my environment is that it runs on Docker, so i need a cert to be generated in runtime for Linux machine, and then used for validating tokens.

In development mode i use AddDeveloperSigninCertificate helper in Startup.cs and it does the job, but i need a cert for production.

Did anyone have same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AddTemporarySigningCredential vs AddSigningCredential in IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572900/addtemporarysigningcredential-vs-addsigningcredential-in-identityserver4)

Comment: The code already generates a certificate, you can just save one to use in production.

Comment: question is not about temporary credentials so it is not a duplicate. also, i need credentials for Docker machine, which is specific. also, i asked for some SigninCredentials example from official docs

Comment: As I understand your question, you want to deploy a certificate with your docker image. Is this not just a question of configuring where to load the file from.  I'm running in production on multiple node and I load the certificate from a file on a share using the AddSigningCredential method.  How the file gets there, is an docker build configuration step, you can add files to images during the build of  an docker image.   Am I still missing the point?

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 yes, but i need to target that file i've added like AddSigningCredential("path_to_file_here"), right? which path from docker container should i set?

Comment: I'm not a docker expert,  you need to somehow map the file to the docker image,  This question seems to try to provide all the possibilities for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388877/adding-files-to-standard-images-using-docker-compose