# How to configure sorry cypress with aws document DB?

Tags: cypress, devops, aws-documentdb, sorrycypress

It's my first time with sorry cypress, I'm trying to get it up but I can't connect it with documentDB.

I would also like to hear experiences with sorry cypress.

I think I need to introduce a .pem to docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with SorryCypress, but my assumptions for connecting to Amazon DocumentDB are:

- Yes, you need the .pem file: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
- Specify the MONGODB_URI, something like this: `mongodb://sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false` - see https://docs.sorry-cypress.dev/configuration/mongodb-configuration for the other variables.
- How to introduce the .pem file?  I see you're using docker-compose, which means you have several [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388877/adding-files-to-standard-images-using-docker-compose) , see which one is convenient for you.

Good luck!