# Docker compose: is it possible to mount a local file to a remote daemon?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-volume

The usage scenario is like this:

I have an AWS EC2 instance already provisioned with **docker-machine**.

I want to use **docker-compose** to **remotely** start a few containers on that EC2 instance.

The compose file has a section like this:

```
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/ubuntu/nginx.tmpl:/app/nginx.tmpl:ro
```

If I use `docker-compose up -d` locally, it'll work, since the "**/home/ubuntu/nginx.tmpl**" file is present on my local machine.

But if I try to use **docker-compose** to control the remote daemon in AWS like this:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://x.y:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="somedir"
docker-compose up -d
```

It'll fail, since the "**/home/ubuntu/nginx.tmpl**" file is not present in the remote machine.

I have tried creating such a file in the remote machine under the same directory, it works, but it feels wrong ... ...

What is a better way to mount a local file to a remote docker daemon?

Comment: I've replied to the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39348811/1556338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Machine has an `scp` command, so you can copy a local file to a remote machine and vice versa:

```
 docker-machine scp ~/my/local/nginx.tmpl machine-name:/home/ubuntu/nginx.tmpl
```

Here's the [reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/scp/).

Comment: I am actually going to be running that command from my CI server. I found out that running scp would require my private key, which I don't want to upload to jenkins